# Cut off text instead of going into a new line - Batch

Tags: batch-file, text, alignment, cut

I am trying to display **cmdtext.txt** in a batch file. I want it to just cut off (just as shown below) when there is no space left instead of going into a new line, because it ruins the "style" and the actual purpose of this file. (The batch file runs maximized, so the text would have enough space to display)

```
________/\\\\\\\\\__/\\\\____________/\\\\__/\\\\\\\\\\\\___________________/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\______________________________/\\\\\\___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
______/\\\////////__\/\\\\\\________/\\\\\\_\/\\\////////\\\________________\///////\\\/////______________________________\////\\\__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
_____/\\\/___________\/\\\//\\\____/\\\//\\\_\/\\\______\//\\\_____________________\/\\\______________________________________\/\\\_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
_____/\\\_____________\/\\\\///\\\/\\\/_\/\\\_\/\\\_______\/\\\__/\\\\\\\\\\\_______\/\\\___________/\\\\\________/\\\\\_______\/\\\_____/\\\\\\\\\\________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
_____\/\\\_____________\/\\\__\///\\\/___\/\\\_\/\\\_______\/\\\_\///////////________\/\\\_________/\\\///\\\____/\\\///\\\_____\/\\\____\/\\\//////________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
______\//\\\____________\/\\\____\///_____\/\\\_\/\\\_______\/\\\_____________________\/\\\________/\\\__\//\\\__/\\\__\//\\\____\/\\\____\/\\\\\\\\\\______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
________\///\\\__________\/\\\_____________\/\\\_\/\\\_______/\\\______________________\/\\\_______\//\\\__/\\\__\//\\\__/\\\_____\/\\\____\////////\\\_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
___________\////\\\\\\\\\_\/\\\_____________\/\\\_\/\\\\\\\\\\\\/_______________________\/\\\________\///\\\\\/____\///\\\\\/____/\\\\\\\\\__/\\\\\\\\\\____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
_______________\/////////__\///______________\///__\////////////_________________________\///___________\/////________\/////_____\/////////__\//////////____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: So what you are saying is that you want it to know when the window is smaller and then cut of the rest? That is not how this works. `cmd` is a command terminal. The entire point is to wrap text to keep it in the view of the user. `cmd` is meant to run commands, which you want to see including its results. It is not intended for displaying ascii images, so live with the wrapping OR keep the window size OR decrease the end of the lines `-------`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch has no builtins for tasks like this. When you wish to format or restrict output, you need to consider what steps you need to take to achieve the goal.

First, consider what information you need. In this task, you need:

- The width of the console in columns

  - Acquire this by iterating over the mode command with a for /f loop
- The data to format

Next, For the purpose of restricting output to the consoles width, Substing modification can be used to trim the data you are formatting to the consoles width:

```bat
@Echo off
Call:Header
Set /A Y=lines,X=columns
Timeout /t 2 /NoBreak
mode 90,30
Call:Header
Timeout /t 2 /NoBreak
mode %X%,%Y%
Goto:Eof


:Header
(Set LF=^


%= Empty lines above required =%)
 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 For /f "tokens=1,2 Delims=: " %%G in ('mode ^| findstr /li "col lin"')Do Set "$%%G=%%H"
 Set "Output="
 For /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims=:1;" %%G in (`type "%~f0" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /blc:":1;" "%~f0"`) Do (
  Set "Line=%%G"
  Set "Output=!Output!!Line:~0,%$Columns%!!LF!"
 )
 Echo(!Output!
 For /f "tokens=1,2 Delims=;" %%G in ("lines=!$lines!;Columns=!$Columns!")Do Endlocal & (
  Set "%%G"
  Set "%%H"
 )
Exit /b


 

:1;________/\\\\\\\\\__/\\\\____________/\\\\__/\\\\\\\\\\\\___________________/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\______________________________/\\\\\\___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
:1;______/\\\////////__\/\\\\\\________/\\\\\\_\/\\\////////\\\________________\///////\\\/////______________________________\////\\\__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
:1;_____/\\\/___________\/\\\//\\\____/\\\//\\\_\/\\\______\//\\\_____________________\/\\\______________________________________\/\\\_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
:1;_____/\\\_____________\/\\\\///\\\/\\\/_\/\\\_\/\\\_______\/\\\__/\\\\\\\\\\\_______\/\\\___________/\\\\\________/\\\\\_______\/\\\_____/\\\\\\\\\\________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
:1;_____\/\\\_____________\/\\\__\///\\\/___\/\\\_\/\\\_______\/\\\_\///////////________\/\\\_________/\\\///\\\____/\\\///\\\_____\/\\\____\/\\\//////________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
:1;______\//\\\____________\/\\\____\///_____\/\\\_\/\\\_______\/\\\_____________________\/\\\________/\\\__\//\\\__/\\\__\//\\\____\/\\\____\/\\\\\\\\\\______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
:1;________\///\\\__________\/\\\_____________\/\\\_\/\\\_______/\\\______________________\/\\\_______\//\\\__/\\\__\//\\\__/\\\_____\/\\\____\////////\\\_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
:1;___________\////\\\\\\\\\_\/\\\_____________\/\\\_\/\\\\\\\\\\\\/_______________________\/\\\________\///\\\\\/____\///\\\\\/____/\\\\\\\\\__/\\\\\\\\\\____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
:1;_______________\/////////__\///______________\///__\////////////_________________________\///___________\/////________\/////_____\/////////__\//////////____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
```